# Python3: Cannot catch stdout of subprocess running `auto-apt -ysi run`

Tags: python, debian, subprocess, apt

I want to match lines start with `Install:` from the output of `auto-apt -ysi run cmake ..` (which runs `cmake` with `auto-apt` in simulation mode). I could get all `stdout` or `stderr` of this command except the lines I want...

**Sample output (manual run):**

```
zhangysh1995@ubuntu-zhangyushao:~/tmp/project/OpenRaider/cbuild$ auto-apt -ysi run cmake ..
Entering auto-apt mode: cmake ..
Exit the command to leave auto-apt mode.
Install:universe/devel/cmake-curses-gui file:/usr/bin/ccmake    by:cmake ..
-- Setting build type to 'Debug' as none was specified.
CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation /home/zhangysh1995/tmp/project/OpenRaider/cbuild/CMakeFiles/git-data/grabRef.cmake.tmp
```

**What I get (`subprocess.check_output`):**

```
Entering auto-apt mode: cmake ..
Exit the command to leave auto-apt mode.
-- Setting build type to 'Debug' as none was specified.
CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation /home/zhangysh1995/tmp/project/OpenRaider/cbuild/CMakeFiles/git-data/grabRef.cmake.tmp
```

This line is missing from `stdout` from my script:

> Install:universe/devel/cmake-curses-gui file:/usr/bin/ccmake
>   by:cmake ..

**Code:**

```
def runSim():
    output = ''
    results = ''

    try:
        process = subprocess.run("auto-apt -ysi run cmake ..", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        # fix: cannot catch `Install:xxx` here
        output = process.stdout.decode('utf-8')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        output = e.output
        # print(output)

    for line in output.splitlines():
        line = line
        if line.startswith("Install:"):
            results += line + ', '

    for pkg in results.split(','):
        print(pkg, end=' ')
```

My question is: could `subprocess.check_output()` get all `stdout` of a subprocess? If yes, is my code correct? If no, what could do to get the lines I want? (I think no because this command c**ould open another subprocess of itself**.)

Comment: Have you tried `stderr`, some programs use `stderr` instead of `stdout`. I beleive if you send both `stderr` and `stdout` to `subprocess.PIPE` you should be able to catch it

Comment: @Ruso_x Actually I have also tried `stderr`, thanks for your reminder. Post updated~

Comment: As far as I can understand, this can happen if your subprocess (directly, or by a call to another subprocess in turn) is bypassing stdout/stderr and writing directly to the tty, or it detects that it is part of a pipe, and therefore skips outputting to stdout. Both of these options sounds a bit far-fetched, but it can happen. In either of those two cases, the solution is to "trick" the program to think it writes directly to the tty, which is done by the `pty` module or, more easily, using `pexpect`.